# Can one app access the events of other apps?

Tags: android

Is it possible that one app can read the events of another app. For example, if I make an app, would I be able to read the events that are happening in other app?
Thanks

Comment: what kind of events are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps run on different processes and are isolated. This serves to protect the operating system from spreading errors and exceptions and also to protect the data that belongs to one app specificy.

Nevertheless, every app can launch an event and your app can filter this event with an intent filter and manage the request that was launched from the other app.

Besides, the app you want to check can operate modifying parameters of the operating system (for example starting an audio track or modifying connectivity) and your app can check if these parameters are varied.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use broadcast or aidl to do this.